# Nested Image Array Fails to Load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to react and javascript (I'm usually backend Java). I'm currently trying to make an image gallery, where the subsections are clicked on and thumbnails of the images within each section are displayed. The thumbnails can then be clicked on and open a lightbox (I'm utilizing [simple-react-lightbox](https://github.com/michelecocuccio/simple-react-lightbox) for this and am on the latest version).

It works, but inconsistently. Sometimes when I click on the thumbnail, instead of throwing up the lightbox and being able to click through the images, it takes me directly to the full sized image.

My nested array with the image data, (imports of images omitted)

```
const GALLERIES =[
    {
        name: 'Beaded Jewelry',
        id: 'beadwork',
        description: 'placeholder',
        resources:[
            {
                id: 1,
                thumbnail: bluependant,
                url: blue,
                title: 'Blue Swarovski Pendant'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                thumbnail: greenpendant,
                url:green,
                title: 'Green Swarovski Pendant'
            }
         ]
       },
 {
        name: 'Wire Jewelry',
        id: 'wirewrapped',
        description: 'placeholder #2',
        resources:[
            {
                id: 'wire1',
                thumbnail: wire1Thumb,
                url: wireWrap1,
                title: 'placholder 1'
            },
            {
                id: 'wire2',
                thumbnail: wire2Thumb,
                url:wireWrap2,
                title: 'placholder 1'
            }
        ]
    }
];
export default GALLERIES
```

And the js that I'm trying to make work consistently.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/gallery.css';
import '../css/jewelry_main.css';
import GALLERIES from '../data/galleries';
import SimpleReactLightbox from "simple-react-lightbox"; 
import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Gallery = props =>{
    const{thumbnail, url, title } = props.subgallery;
    return(
        <div className="gallery">
            <a href={url} data-attribute="SRL">
            <img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}

const JewelryGallery = ({match}) =>{
const gallery = GALLERIES.find(({ id }) => id === match.params.keyword)
    return(
        <div>
        <div className="frosted">
        <p>{gallery.description}</p>
        </div>
        <SimpleReactLightbox>
            <SRLWrapper>
            {
                gallery.resources.map((SUBGALLERY) =>{
                    return(
                        <Gallery key = {SUBGALLERY.id} subgallery={SUBGALLERY} />
                    )
                })
            }
            </SRLWrapper>
            </SimpleReactLightbox>
       </div>
    );

}

export default JewelryGallery;
```

Any insight or wisdom would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

UPDATE EDIT: I noticed something, the first subgallery I click into will always present with the lightbox, but the second one, consistently fails and instead goes directly to the fullsize of whichever image I have clicked on. (It doesn't matter which of the two I pick first, the second always fails.) But I can't discern why the lightbox would not get applied to the second gallery I select.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two things I can see that differ from the documentation for the `simple-react-lightbox` package.

First thing is, with the latest version, you only need to use the `<SRLWrapper>` component. You have both the `<SRLWrapper>` and the `<SimpleReactLightbox>` component in use. Perhaps try getting rid of the old version if you have the latest version of the package installed.

Second thing is the structure of your `Gallery` component return has the `div` wrapping the elements. I'm not sure if this would cause any problems but, to get as close as possible to the example in the docs you could try using a fragment instead of a `div`.

```
    const{thumbnail, url, title } = props.subgallery;
    return(
        <>
            <a href={url} data-attribute="SRL">
            <img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />
            </a>
        </>
    )
```

I haven't used the package so this is a bit of speculation. Hope it leads you in the right direction though.

EDIT

I think I misunderstood this library a bit. You do need both of those components. It looks like if you want to display full size images, you would do it the way you have it currently. However, if you want to use the lightbox feature with the nav at the bottom you would need to do something like:

```
          <SimpleReactLightbox>
            <SRLWrapper>
            <div id="content-page-one" className="container content">
            <div className="row">
            {
                gallery.resources.map((SUBGALLERY) =>{
                    return(
                        <Gallery key = {SUBGALLERY.id} subgallery={SUBGALLERY} />
                    )
                })
            }
            </div>
            </div>
            </SRLWrapper>
          </SimpleReactLightbox>
```

And then you would use `div` instead of an anchor tag:

```
<div className="col-md-6 col-12 col-image-half">
  <img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />
</div>
```

This is pulled from the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-lightboxss-39wrb?fontsize=10) examples they have. I would take a closer look there and see if they have the exact setup you're looking for. Notice also that they are using the Bootstrap styling framework as well, so in order for those styles to work you would need to install bootstrap to your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have tried removing the ```<SimpleReactLightBox>``` and using a fragment, (independent of each other and in tandem), unfortunately neither worked. Removing the ```<SimpleReactLightBox>``` caused the whole page not to load and using a fragment still resulted in the the lightbox failing to trigger and taking me directly to the image.

Comment: I took a look at the docs again and added an edit to the answer. I missed some stuff I think. If you want to go over the edit and take a look at the code sandbox they provide in there docs, hopefully it can get you where you need to go.

Comment: Ah okay I've never been able to get the sandbox code to load for me! I'll give this a try and get back to you! Thanks again for taking the time to help!

Comment: No dice unfortunately. BUT I have noticed something peculiar, the first subgallery I select, always presents with the lightbox. The second subgallery always fails to display the lightbox and just goes directly to the full image. Doesn't matter which one I do first or second, behavior remains the same.